# How can a process "lose" it's connection to stdout?

Tags: linux, docker

I'm running the following script in my linux devcontainer (ubuntu 20:04), running on a popos host:

```
nohup ./scripts/build/_build-server --compile --watch > /home/dark/app/rundir/logs/build-server.log &
```

Recently [1], the script regularly stops sending output to the log file (at different times in the execution). The script continues to run - I can see other processes that it spawns. The log file continues to exist, but it gets no new output.

How can I figure out what's going wrong? (What commands would be useful? What terms should I be googling?)

[1] This now happens every time I start the script. It started when I upgraded the host docker OS to Pop!_OS 22:04

Comment: Maybe try `strace` to capture the syscalls it's making?

Comment: Good idea, thanks @JurajMartinka

Comment: Using `nohup` in modern shells isn't buying you anything and could be adding to your problems.

Comment: Thanks @chicks. Can you tell me more?

Comment: The main purpose of `nohup` is to keep something running in the background after you log out.  But in job-control shells (ksh, bash, zsh, etc.) they do this for you already and so `nohup` is unneeded baggage from a bygone era.  Also, `nohup` will redirect your output stream to a file `nohup.out` which could be where your log output has ended up.